# How to determine if the limit $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac1{a_N}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $a_{n}>0$, and let $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=a$; then
does this limit converge to some finite number?

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\dfrac{a-\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}}{a_{N}}$$

Comment: How do you know that the limit exists at all?

Comment: @Ilya That's precisely OPs question.

Comment: Yes,that's mean.@Ilya,Thank you

Comment: Unless I am missing something- Since the sum of $a_n$ converges to a finite value shouldn't it be the case that $a_n$ is finite for every $n$ and hence the limit is $0$?

Comment: You do not have a definite answer, it is easy to cook up examples such the limit exist/not exist.

Comment: @MaMing Post a counterexample as an answer, then

Answer (score 3):

Below are two examples, of which one converges and the other diverges.

- $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$, it is easy to see this converges.
- $a_n=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, it is easy to see this diverges.

Comment: +1. A little more general: If $a_n$ decreases potentially, then the sequence grows linearly.

Comment: @leonbloy so, would you say that my intuition was off as convergence depends on how fast the numerator decreases relative to the denominator?

Comment: @response: basically yes, look at the new question title. It's clear that both numberator and denominator tend to zero. To get a more reliable intuition, you could try the continuous analog (integrals instead of sums)